# Can we use a CASE...WHEN inside SUBSTRING?

Tags: sql, postgresql

(Here's a much simpler case of my actual conundrum at work)

Let's say I have a table, called 'a', with a column named 'col' with the following values (say a column of length 2 with many random combination of characters):

```
col
A3 
D2 
@5
#)
...
```

I want to use a select statement that outputs two columns called 'letter' and 'number' where 'letter' is the first character of 'col' & 'number' is the second character of 'col', but with the following mapping:

```
If substring(col FROM 1 for 1) in ('!','@','#'),
    then letter = 'A' and 'number' = substring(col FROM 2 for 1)
```

(i.e., if the first character of something in 'col' is '!', '@', or '#', map it
to 'letter' as 'A' while keeping the second character of 'col' the same and 
mapping that value to 'number')

```
If col = '%9', 
    then 'letter' = 'H' and 'number' = '9'
```

(i.e., if a specific value in 'col' is '%9', then map it to 'letter' as 'H' and
'number' as '9')

```
If substring(col FROM 2 for 1) = '4',
    then 'letter' = substring(col FROM 1 for 1) and 'number' = '7'
```

(i.e., if the second character of a value in 'col' is '4', leave the first
character unchanged and map it to 'letter' and map the second character to
'number' as '7')

Lastly, only select values where 'letter' is a letter and 'number' is a one
character number. That is,

```
'letter' in ('A','B',...'Z') and 'number' in ('0','1',...'9')
```

What query would I run to solve this? That is, with the mapping hardcoded using CASE..WHEN?

Ideally, I'm trying to do something like:

```
SELECT substring((Case...When) FROM 1 for 1) AS letter,
substring((Case...When) FROM 2 for 1) AS number
FROM a;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please edit the question to show sample data and desired results.  That can be a big help for others to understand the logic.

Comment: I've edited the OP to make it more explicit.

Comment: Still pretty hard to follow. Some mappings of input -> output can be very helpful. Overall it sounds like you just want a series of substitution rules - probably one or more regular expressions will do nicely.

Comment: I asked a previous question with an input->output but the answers weren't in the format I was asking for (the CASE..WHEN inside a substring).

Here's a more generalized form of my question: 

Assume you have a column 'col' with two characters. I want a SELECT statement that splits the values from 'col' into two columns--one for the first and second character of 'col' but with certain conditions/substitutions/exclusions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT
CASE 
  WHEN SUBSTRING(COL from 1 for 1) IN ('!','@','#') THEN 'A'
  WHEN COL LIKE '%9' THEN 'H'
  WHEN SUBSTRING(COL,2,1) = '4' THEN SUBSTRING(COL,1)
END Letter,
CASE 
  WHEN SUBSTRING(COL from 1 for 1) IN ('!','@','#') THEN substring(col FROM 2 for 1)
  WHEN COL LIKE '%9' THEN '9'
  WHEN SUBSTRING(COL,2,1) = '4' THEN '7'
END Number
FROM A
) 
WHERE (Letter ~ '^[A-Za-z]$') = true AND (Number ~ '^[0-9]$') = true;
```